# How to remove last BR elements in a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove the last `<BR>`s in a div with jQuery. I tried this code but it removes the line break tags at the first and the middle too.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="topic">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.<br/>
 Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,<br/> 
 nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
 Nulla consequat massa quis enim. DonecLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.<br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.topic').find('br').remove();
});
```

Comment: What should happen if there was a `<div>` between the last and penultimate `<br/>` elements?

Comment: You want to deleted with an button?

Comment: are you generating this with PHP or similar? Why not trim the text before sending it to `nl2br()`?

Comment: @MightyPork The code is generated with external resource that I don't have the ability to change it.

Comment: @DiegoCardenas No I wan't to delete it automatically.

Comment: [jquery :gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Comment: $('br').remove(); just add this into the jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm aware this isn't what you asked, but I imagine you are trying to remove extra visual breaks. If so, it's less impactful to just do it with css:

```
br + br{display:none;}
```

This will leave just the first break functioning as a break, while all it's siblings are hidden.

Comment: Guess what happens when you use this CSS on `<div>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5</div>`.

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach:

```
// selecting the <br /> element that is a last-child:
$('br:last-child')
// selecting all previous-sibling elements until we find one that is not a <br /> element:
.prevUntil(':not(br)')
// adding the initial selector back to the collection:
.addBack()
// filtering the collection:
.filter(function() {
  var sibling = this.previousSibling;
  // keeping only those <br /> elements with a previous-sibling of nodeType === 3
  // (a textNode), and those whose previous-sibling's nodeValue (with leading
  // and trailing white-space removed) is equal to 0:
  return sibling.nodeType === 3 && sibling.nodeValue.trim().length === 0;
// removing those elements:
}).remove();
```

```js
$('br:last-child').prevUntil(':not(br)').addBack().filter(function() {
  var sibling = this.previousSibling;
  return sibling.nodeType === 3 && sibling.nodeValue.trim().length === 0;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topic">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
  <br />Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
  <br />nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. DonecLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

References:

- [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
- [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
- [`prevUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/).

Comment: how did you do the spoiler thingy? Is there a tutorial on that?

Comment: The... 'Show code snippet' thing? That's just a stack snippet (like JS Fiddle, basically). When writing an answer, or question, click the icon with a pencil that sits over the textarea (next to the image icone) and it brings up the editor.

Comment: ah nice. must be something new, I've never seen it used before.

Comment: Per the OP's original example, shouldn't you restrict it to being within `$('.topic')`, otherwise, it's going to remove the last BR child of every tag that has BRs within it.

Comment: This is _way_ to aggressive... it deletes all `br`s in the content. You need to stop if there is a non-empty text node.

Comment: @Salman: no, it doesn't; it removes "*the last Br's in a div*" note the plural. It's ambiguous quite what it means, but I interpreted it to mean 'trailing `<br />` elements,' your take would be..?

Comment: @Salman: the updated approach seems to work (on inspecting the DOM), could you verify?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.topic').find('br:last-child').remove();
}
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: @MightyPork, I think you might be mistaken as the documents specifically state that the :last-child (as opposed to :last) will match "more than one: one for each parent."

Comment: What about the ones before the last one?

Comment: @SalmanA, I'm not sure what you mean. This will only match BRs that are the last-child per `.topic`.  The ones before that will be ignored by the selector.  See the docs link I added, which has an example of adding red color to the last-child.

Comment: _remove the last **Br's** in a div_... there are four consecutive brs at the end, all should be removed.

Comment: @SalmanA, ah, I see...I didn't understand that from the OP's question. I thought he literally meant "the last one", not every subsequent one after the first.

Comment: @SalmanA, my mistake is that I see Br's as "possessive" not "plural" and thus I just ignored it as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.topic').find('br:last').remove();
});
```

Using the `:last` selector, it will take the last matched element.

Comment: it will delete the last br in the document

Answer (score 0):

with `$('br').remove();` look the example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/u2vS6/101/)

Comment: This will remove all Br tags and I want to remove just last one's

Comment: Well you can used with selector :) $('#SelectorName' 'br').remove();

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('#customID br:last-child').remove();
```

This remove the last br tag from custom tag.

Note: I have used Jquery version 3.1.1